# Converting xml to codes

Tags: android, xml

Can anyone make my xml to codes in android?

I'd like to make a new button with same position,relation,height and width programmatically like the xml that I attached here. I read some questions here in stackoverflow but I don't understand. I'm not good in English. Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="New Buttons" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: I have an application that get the number of data in database and also it will automatically create a button for every data, if the database server add a new data . my application will refresh and add new button for that new data .

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with LayoutParams for references go through this link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

android for the further more understanding on layouts i prefer you reading this blog :
http://blog.vogella.com/2011/03/14/android-hacking-layouts/

Sample code on Layoutparams :

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // creating LinearLayout
            LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            // specifying vertical orientation
            linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            // creating LayoutParams  
            LayoutParams linLayoutParam = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); 
            // set LinearLayout as a root element of the screen 
            setContentView(linLayout, linLayoutParam);

            LayoutParams lpView = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("TextView");
            tv.setLayoutParams(lpView);
            linLayout.addView(tv);

            Button btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setText("Button");
            linLayout.addView(btn, lpView);


            LinearLayout.LayoutParams leftMarginParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            leftMarginParams.leftMargin = 50;

            Button btn1 = new Button(this);
            btn1.setText("Button1");
            linLayout.addView(btn1, leftMarginParams);


            LinearLayout.LayoutParams rightGravityParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            rightGravityParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;

            Button btn2 = new Button(this);
            btn2.setText("Button2");
            linLayout.addView(btn2, rightGravityParams);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an online service to do that for you at [XML2Java](http://www.xmltojava.com)

From the website:

> What's Android XML to JAVA?
>
> Do you wanna design UI of your Android Apps without using any XML code? Do you wanna make your life easier when you were designing a dynamic UI for some Android App? Do you wanna save time developing your App rather than spending most of it trying to design UI? This is over now with Android XML2Java. This service provides an automatic conversion of Android XML codes (tags and Attributes) to equivalent Android Java methods. All you need is some XML code and you are good to go.

or you could do it manually. Explore the API docs at [Android Developers Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android) and some tutorials on how to use those APIs like [TutsPlus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-layout-basics--mobile-3671).